# Add onkeyup attribute to div using a function

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to add `onkeyup="Preview.Update()"` as an attribute to a `div`.

Is there any way I could do this with a function since the `div` is incorporated into a plugin on Wordpress and I don't want to edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$("#yourDivID").attr("onkeyup", "Preview.Update()");
```

Comment: Sorry quite new to wordpress... do I just put that in functions.php of wordpress theme? Thanks for reply.

Comment: No in `<script>` tags on the HTML side of the theme. But my example is to add an attribute to an element. If there are multiple `MathInputs` on the page it's easier to use C.Raf.T example of a `listener`.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div").onkeyup= function() {
    Preview.Update();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The div id which i want to apply the function to is MathInput so would I write document.getElementsByTagName("MathInput").onkeyup= function() {
    Preview.Update();
}

Comment: @Jack  document.getElementById("MathInput")

Comment: Thanks again. It says parse error when I do that "unexpected =" ? Any ideas?

Comment: @Jack may be your script run before plugin and script don't know what's id "MathInput"...

Comment: Thanks C.Raf.T for help :)